# How to modify / remove the bottom bar in Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, desktop, display-settings, dock

How can we remove the "bottom bar" (that has all the icons) in Mac OS X? :

[image]

Also, is it possible to move it  to the left or right side of the screen like how Windows taskbar  does it? :

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 18, accepted):

What do you mean by "bottom bar"? The dock?

---

### Hiding the dock

#### Version 1 - Hiding

By pressing <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> you hide it (works also by clicking "Turn Hiding On", see below). It will then disappear but reappear when you move your mouse over the Dock area at the bottom.

When hidden, application windows take up the full space, so maybe this is just what you're looking for.

#### Version 2 - Making it really small

If this isn't enough, you can also go to *Terminal.app* and enter:

```
defaults write com.apple.dock tilesize -int 1
killall Dock
```

Then the dock will be so super small that you won't even notice it. If you hide it then, it won't get in your way. There will be just a very tiny area that you have to hover over to see it.

#### Version 3 - Removing it entirely

There's a programm called [DockDisabler](http://www.chaoticsoftware.com/extras.html), which is supposed to remove it entirely.

**Warning:** This may break some things so I wouldn't recommend it unless you know what you're doing.

---

### Moving the Dock to the side of the screen

Just right-click the dock these stripes you see on the right, and change the position.

[image]

Note that all of these commands can also be accessed from the Apple menu (under Dock), or in System Preferences → Dock.

Answer (score 7):

This one works for me (in OS X 10.8):

```
defaults write com.apple.dock autohide-delay -float 9999999
killall Dock
```

It makes Dock wait long enough before show up.

Answer (score 4):

You can't get rid of the Dock entirely, but you can get really close. This method is completely safe and will not damage your computer. Enjoy

1. Make it really small.

   ```
   defaults write com.apple.dock tilesize -int 1; killall Dock
   ```
2. Hide it, and never let it come back, even when you scroll your mouse to the bottom.

   ```
   defaults write com.apple.dock autohide-time-modifier -float 20000000000; killall Dock
   ```

   You can change 20000000000 to any number. It represents the delay in seconds for the Dock to appear and disappear.

Done, your Dock won't show up unless you hold your mouse at the bottom of your screen for 20000000000 seconds! And if it does, it will be puny.