# How to disable OSX dock

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, desktop, dock

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I remove the Dock in Mac OS X?](https://superuser.com/questions/277996/how-can-i-remove-the-dock-in-mac-os-x)

After installing quicksilver I rarely need to use the OSX (snow leopard) dock. I would like to disable the OSX dock from showing up unless I summon it with Command-Option-D. At the moment I can hide it, but when my mouse touches the edge it shows up.

Is there a way to disable the dock from showing up automatically? I can disable "automatically hide and show the dock" in the system preferences, but that just means it's shown all the time (seems like a bit of a silly assumption).

Comment: ... and [How to remove the Dock in Mac OS X Leopard](http://superuser.com/questions/18244/how-to-remove-the-dock-in-mac-os-x-leopard)

Answer (score 5):

Stuff like Expose and virtual desktops live also in the Dock process, so if you quit Dock, you also lose these features.

There is a way to make it really tiny though:

```
defaults write com.apple.dock tilesize -integer 1 && killall Dock
```

Dock will restart afterwards and be really tiny.

Answer (score 0):

Create an AppleScript with the code below and add it to your login items, the dock will open for a few seconds but should then disappear.

```
tell application "Dock"
  activate
  quit
end tell
```

Hope this helps.